# Getting the index of the first K values in a mixed index pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

L'ets say I have a pandas Series called z:

```
index  items
155    14
2      555
1445   23
855     3
```

and so on. As you can see, the indexes were mixed. How can I, without changing the current indexing, get a list of the index of the K first few rows?
For exemple, for K=3, I want this: [155,2,1445]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `iloc` with *slice*:

```
s.iloc[:3].index
```

Or use `head`:

```
s.head(3).index
```

---

```
s
#index
#155      14
#2       555
#1445     23
#855       3
#Name: items, dtype: int64

s.iloc[:3].index.values
#array([ 155,    2, 1445], dtype=int64)

s.head(3).index.values
#array([ 155,    2, 1445], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: but it will give me the values, isnt it ? i want the inexes

Answer (score 0):

If `z` is Series then need only:

```
L = z.index[:3].tolist()
```

EDIT by comment:

It seems you get `DataFrame` and `index` is column:

```
print (type(z))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

#set index with column index
z = z.set_index('index')
#select values by position and convert to list
L = z.index[:3].tolist()
print (L)
[155, 2, 1445]
```

If index is column is possible select column and then get first N values by position with [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
L = z['index'].iloc[:3].tolist()
```

Better is use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), but need position of `index` column too by [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html):

```
L = z.iloc[:3, df.columns.get_loc('index')].tolist()
```

Comment: thank you. this is what i get: "RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)"...its nnot the names of the indexes.